# How to get status of long running task

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task

Why does the `Status` of my `Task` return "WaitingForActivasion" instead of "Running" ?
If I remove `Task.Run` I get stuck in the `while` loop, so I assume its not running asynchronous.

```
public class StateManagerTest
{
    [Fact]
    public void Start_TaskStatus()
    {
        StateManager manager = new StateManager();
        manager.Start();

        Assert.True(manager.Status == System.Threading.Tasks.TaskStatus.Running.ToString());
    }
}

public class StateManager
{
    private CancellationTokenSource cts = new();
    private Task updateTask;
    public HashSet<StateItem> StateItems { get; private set; }
    public Provider Provider { get; private set; }
    public List<OutputService> OutputServices { get; private set; }

    public string Status
    {
        get => updateTask.Status.ToString();
    }

    public StateManager()
    {
        StateItems = new();
        OutputServices = new();
        Provider = new();
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        cts.Cancel();
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        updateTask = Task.Run(() => Update(cts.Token))
            .ContinueWith(t => Debug.WriteLine(t.Exception.Message), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
    }

    private async Task Update(CancellationToken token)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            // get changes from outputs
            Dictionary<StateItem, object> changes = new Dictionary<StateItem, object>();
            foreach (var service in OutputServices)
            {
                var outputChanges = await service.GetChanges();
                foreach (var change in outputChanges)
                    changes.TryAdd(change.Key, change.Value);
            }

            // write changes to provider source
            await Provider.PushChanges(changes);

            // update state
            await Provider.UpdateStateItems();

            // update all services
            foreach (var service in OutputServices)
                await service.UpdateSource();

            if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
                return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/the-meaning-of-taskstatus/

Comment: @TheGeneral Thanks for the information. But is the while loop in Update() still being executed? Or is there something wrong with my Start() method?

Comment: "But is the while loop in Update() still being executed" - yes, well until its not... But I think the broader question is what are you actually trying to achieve here?

Comment: @TheGeneral I want to run the Update() task in the background without awaiting it. To check if its running I wanted to check the task status.

Comment: `async Task Start() { await Update(cts.Token); // at this point your task has finished, do whatever`, there is little need to poll a task for completeness

Comment: The `Task.Run` with asynhcronous lambda (or with a lambda that returns a `Task` like in your case) creates a promise-style task. Promise-style tasks never transition to the `Running` state. You can look here for more details: [A Tour of Task, Part 3: Status](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/a-tour-of-task-part-3-status.html)

Comment: @TheodorZoulias even without Task.Run it would still be WaitingForActivasion

Comment: @TheGeneral yes, because the `Update` is an asynchronous method, and asynchronous methods return promise-style tasks.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias just making it clear :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have noted, [`WaitingForActivation` is the correct state for a Promise Task that is not yet completed](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/a-tour-of-task-part-3-status.html). In general, I recommend not using `Task.Status` or `ContinueWith`; they are relics from a time before `async`/`await` existed.

> How to get status of long running task

I believe you would want [progress reporting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/task-based-asynchronous-pattern-tap#progress-reporting-optional), which is done yourself. The `T` in `IProgress<T>` can be a `string` if you want a simple text update, or a `double` if you want a percentage update, or a custom `struct` if you want a more complex update.